# How to preview multiple sites on single domain name/IP address?

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm running Apache2 on an Ubuntu instance in EC2. Apache is currently serving three sites, none of which have separate domain names as yet.

What's the easiest way to configure the server to allow me to preview the sites individually through a remote browser? Visiting the server by way of its IP address in the browser just gives me the base page from /var/www/ of course. I need to know how to set it up so I can access like http://[IP_ADDRESS]/[site1], http://[IPADDRESS]/[site2] etc.

I've tried mapping it in my local hosts file on my Ubuntu client - [IP ADDRESS] [domain name as in vhost] but no joy - I'm still getting shunted to the base page.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a browser extension to force the `Host` header to a specific value.

Comment: Thanks. Would be grateful if you could expand on that please.

Comment: See section 14.23 of [RFC 2616, "Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1"](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

Comment: That's much appreciated and I now have a better grasp of the concept.

Can you recommend an extension?